# Straightforward way to replicate server running with LVM

Tags: linux, partitioning, lvm, clonezilla, replication

I have used Clonezilla to take an image of an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server that has 4x4TB disks with a single LVM volume spanning them. I did see Clonezilla making an image of the LVM data volume by name ("datavolume" in volume group "datazone"), so in some sense it seems to work. The problem is, I have no idea how to restore this image to another machine. If I just run a Clonezilla restoration naïvely, it complains that the UUIDs of the LVM disks aren't the same and the computer explodes. Well, not quite, but I don't get my server replicated as desired.

My desired replication destination is an older server that only runs in BIOS that has 4x8TB disks. I have been able to get a blank Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with a similar layout going, although there has been some grief.

Source disk layout pictured below.

Pastebin of "clonezilla-img": https://pastebin.com/KYKmt6iR

Pastebin of file listing (`ls -lah` inside the image folder): https://pastebin.com/Y3Y3Kfgi

[image: Layout of original server]

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing was discovering that this old server actually did support UEFI! Was just on BIOS mode by default. So after putting the server into UEFI mode, I was able to boot Clonezilla in UEFI mode off a USB stick and was able to restore my image normally. (I did go through Advanced Mode, in case I saw something that I wanted to try changing, but I just took the defaults.)

I hasten to add that this was a 4x4TB LVM setup restored to 4x8TB real disks. Later I would like to try restoring to, e.g., 4x5TB virtual disks in a virtual machine. But that's another project for another day.